# Help with SED to replace

Tags: sed, replace

I want to replace
`C:\Documents and Settings\sjohnson4\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Squirrel.exe`
with
`C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Squirrel.exe`.

```
echo "C:\Documents and Settings\sjohnson4\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Squirrel.exe" | \
    sed  -e 's/\\Documents and Settings\\*\\/\\Documents and Settings\\USERNAME\\/'
```

results in

```
C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\sjohnson4\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Squirrel.exe
```

while

```
echo "C:\Documents and Settings\sjohnson4\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Squirrel.exe" | \
    sed  -e 's/\\Documents and Settings\\.*\\/\\Documents and Settings\\USERNAME\\/'
```

returns

```
C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Squirrel.exe
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what your asking this should work for you if will replace "sjohnson4" with USERNAME.

```
sed 's/sjohnson4/USERNAME/'
```

This will search for and replace sjohnson4 if this isn't what you need let me know.

Jason C.

Answer (score 1):

Using backslash (`\`) as a field separator, the following would use `awk` to replace the 3rd field with the string `USERNAME` unconditionally:

```bsh
awk -F '\' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } { $3 = "USERNAME"; print }'
```

Testing:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'C:\Documents and Settings\sjohnson4\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Squirrel.exe' | awk -F '\' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } { $3 = "USERNAME"; print }'
C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Squirrel.exe
```

---

A similar approach as the above using `sed`:

```bsh
sed 's/[^\]*\\/USERNAME\\/3'
```

This replaces the 3rd match of `[^\]*\\` (any number of non-backslashes, followed by a backslash) with the string `USERNAME\`.

Testing:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'C:\Documents and Settings\sjohnson4\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Squirrel.exe' | sed 's/[^\]*\\/USERNAME\\/3'
C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Squirrel.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match any "username" in there

`sed -E "s,(^.+and Settings\\\)[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\\AppData.+$),\1USERNAME\2,"`

Example:

```
$ echo "C:\Documents and Settings\ThisIsAnotherUsername15\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Squirrel.exe" | sed -E "s,(^.+and Settings\\\)[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\\AppData.+$),\1USERNAME\2," 
C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Squirrel.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

To just correct your script with minimal changes:

```
$ echo 'C:\Documents and Settings\sjohnson4\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Squirrel.exe' |
    sed 's/\(\\Documents and Settings\\\)[^\\]*/\1USERNAME/'
C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current\Squirrel.exe
```